# How to setq a variable for a script in the command line?

Tags: command-line-arguments

I was confused by this problem when I tried to `setq` a switch variable for an Elisp script in the command line.

So I had a script `~/tmp/test.el` referring to a variable: `(message "foo %S" foo)`, then I ran this command `emacs -Q --eval "(setq foo t)" --script ~/tmp/test.el`. To my surprise, it errored out complaining that `(void-variable foo)`. And I failed to find something helpful in man and google.

How to resolve this?

Emacs version is 28.3 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause is that the `--script` file is loaded before `--eval` expressions. (`--eval` expressions, `--funcall` calls and `--load` files are evaluated in the order they appear on the command line.)

```
% emacs -Q --batch --load =(echo '(message "load 1")') --eval '(message "eval 1")' --script =(echo '(message "script")') --eval '(message "eval 2")' --load =(echo '(message "load 2")')
script
load 1
eval 1
eval 2
load 2
```

I can't find anything in the documentation that suggests this ordering.

Looking at the source code, [`--script`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.2/src/emacs.c#L2383) is a high-priority option, like `--batch`, whereas [`--eval`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.2/src/emacs.c#L2474), `--load` and such have priority 0. Emacs processes options in order of decreasing priority. [`--script` gets special handling](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.2/src/emacs.c#L1602), after which its option is [re-ordered](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.2/src/emacs.c#L2500) at the front of the priority-0 options (using the internal name [`-scriptload`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/emacs-28.2/src/emacs.c#L2471)). It seems to me that this is an unintended side effect of the way `--script` is handled in two stages: the `--batch` aspect needs to be handled early, but other than that a `--script` should be treated like `--load` for ordering purposes. However, as we'll see below, this wouldn't make any difference in the common use case for `--script`.

If you can change the command line, you can use `--batch --load` instead of `--script`. Apart from the difference in ordering, they are almost equivalent; the main difference is that `--load foo` looks in `load-path` and also tries `foo.elc` and `foo.el`, whereas `--script foo` wants `foo`.

This won't help you if `--script` is in a shebang line. Even if the option didn't get reordered, it would still be first on the command line, hence evaluated before any `--eval` passed on the script's command line. You would need some kind of `--early-eval` option such that `emacs --batch --load foo.el --early-eval '(bar)'` runs `(bar)` *before* loading `foo.el`. But there is no such option.

If you really need to set a variable before running a script, or more generally if you need to run some code before running a script, you can put the code in one of the [files that Emacs loads during its startup](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html). This includes files in the `load-path`, which is set from the environment variable `EMACSLOADPATH`, so you don't have to change a standard file. Add a directory to `EMACSLOADPATH` and put your code in `subdirs.el`.

```
% cat subdirs.el
(setq foo "subdirs")
% emacs --batch --load =(echo '(print foo)')
Symbol’s value as variable is void: foo
 EMACSLOADPATH="$EMACSLOADPATH:$PWD" emacs --batch --load =(echo '(print foo)')

"subdirs"
```

Note that this is not an intended method to pass data to a script. Scripts are intended to start in the pristine Emacs, plus site customizations unless disabled with `-Q`, plus user customizations unless disabled with `-q`. Setting extra Lisp variables is debug-level modification of the environment. The intended ways to pass data to a script are through an environment variable or a command line argument.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation, Gilles! I solved it using a slightly adapted approach based on your suggestion in the test.el: `(setq foo (string= "YES" (getenv "FOO")))`. Thank you!

Comment: @whatacold: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211087/324105 useful.